# Multiple CSS transitions in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My HTML is:

```
<nav id="card-set-menu-nav" ng-style="cardSetMenuNavStyle">
...
</nav>
```

And my Javascript code using AngularJS is like:

```
$scope.openCardSetMenu = function(cardSet) {
    $scope.cardSetMenuNavStyle = {'transition':'0.25s', 'left':'100%')};
    $scope.cardSetMenuNavStyle = {'transition':'0.25s', 'left':'50%')};
};
```

I want to implement simple side menu by changing **$scope.cardSetMenuNavStyle** variable.

HTML element **card-set-menu-nav** will be put at left:100% then be pulled out to left:50% like.

But it does not work. It does not move at all after the first unfolding... Maybe transitions are ignored because the final result is the same?

How can I apply multiple CSS transitions on an HTML element.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis `)` at the end of your style declaration

Answer (score 0):

you setting the styles inside a function **openCardSetMenu** and ensure that the function is called and remove the extra close brace **)** in both the lines of angular code..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the extra parenthesis `)` at the end of the style declarations.

Second: do you really need to use AngularJS? I think you can use CSS `transition` instead, and "concatenate" transitions with commas and the `transition-delay` property.

See [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) in W3Schools for more information about transitions.

Comment: Please do not post links to W3Schools (or use them at all, for that matter), See [here](http://w3fools.com) for an explaination

Comment: @MayorMonty OK, but in this case, that page have good fully-functional examples that could help.

Comment: The problem is that since W3Schools is privately curated, it takes much longer for it to update than [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) or the [Web Platform Docs](http://www.webplatform.org/) and it is frequently behind the spec

Answer (score 0):

The css [`transitions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property supports transitions for multiple different properties like so:

```
element {
  transitions: 0.2s left 0.3s color 0.4s 0.8s all
}
```

Now, if you're setting multiple transitions on one element, I would recommend you look at the [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property and setting custom easings. As for implementing these in AngularJS, I'm not super familiar with it, but it seems like you should use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive

Hope this was helpful!